# Executing python in windows via notepad (F6 Exec command __main__ error)

Tags: python, windows, module

I have notepad++ installed on win7, and have installed the notepad++ exec plugin.  Whenever I execute the .py script I am running, i get the following error:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe ""
Process started >>>
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
<<< Process finished.
================ READY ================
```

My index.py script is as follows:

```
text = "Hello World"
print text
```

The Notepad++ execute script (F6) is as follows:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe "$(C:/Python27/python.exe)"
```

This is the correct path to python.exe on my system.  In the windows environmental variables, I have also added this to the PATH.  Also, I have booted up the python.exe command prompt and have gotten the script to work by manually typing it in.  I have done a directory search of C:/Python27, and the **main**.py file exists.

What is going on that is wrong here?  Why can't python find the __ main __ module??

**EDIT:**

Nevermind this, I'm an idiot.

So I had misinterpreted the setup for the notepad++ exec (F6) script:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe "$(C:/Python27/python.exe)"
```

It should have been this instead:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Of course it couldn't find the **main**.py file because it wasn't going to FULL_CURRENT_PATH.
Carry on.

Comment: Actually, just to be clear, `__main__` is a predefined name in Python, specifically the top-level module being executed. It's not related to you naming the file "main.py". Sometimes, in Python modules, you'll see `if __name__ == '__main__':` near the bottom of the module, usually followed by test code or a call to the main function of the module. The code in this `if` block is executed if the module is run directly by Python instead of via an `import` statement. (This is also related to why you see `.pyc` files generated for modules you `import` but not for the one you execute.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's because the 1st argument in your script has been missinterpreted.
That is to say, with the code

```
C:/python27/python.exe "$(C:/python27/python.exe)"
```

You're doing something roughly equivalent

```
C:/python27/python.exe
```

What you need to use is:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Note: Don't substitute "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" for something else - put that in verbatim - it's  a predefined variable of the NppExec plugin. It may be considered shorthand for the full-path of the file in the currently open tab.

When I execute the script above (on a file called tmp.py, in my c:\xampp\htdocs\enhzflep folder), I get this displayed in the console:

> C:/Python27/python.exe "C:\xampp\htdocs\enhzflep\tmp.py"
>   CreateProcess() failed with error code 2: The system cannot find the
>   file specified.

Which is just fine, since I don't have python installed on this machine. :)

EDIT: Just saw your edit. It seems I'm the greater fool!